# Difference Between Dates and List of Dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am dealing with a dataset containing patients COVID related data.

In my dataset, I have as variables:

1. List of Dates on which the swab test resulted positive: "LIST OF POSITIVE DATES"
2. Date of Admission to the hospital: "DATE OF ADMISSION"
3. Date of Discharge: "DATE OF DISCHARGE"

My objective would be to

1. Check if one of the dates in the list of positive dates comes 15 days before the date of admission.
   Hence something like DATE OF ADMISSION - DATE IN LIST OF POSITIVE DATES = < 15
2. Check if one of the dates in the list of positive dates falls in the time range from the date of admission ( "DATE OF ADMISSION") and the date of discharge  ( "DATE OF DISCHARGE").
   Hence something like
   DATE OF ADMISSION < DATE IN THE LIST OF POSITIVE DATES  < DATE OF DISCHARGE
3. Check if one of the dates in the list of positive dates comes 15 days after the DATE DISCHARGE
   Hence something like
   DATE IN THE LIST OF POSITIVE DATES - DATE DISCHARGE< 15

To do so, first I converted the target date (DATA_RIC) in the date object.

```
df["DATE OF ADMISSION"] = df["DATE OF ADMISSION"].apply(lambda a: pd.to_datetime(a,format='%Y/%m/%d',errors="coerce").date())
```

Then I converted the list to a list of datetime objects.

```
df["LIST OF POSITIVE DATES"] = [x.split(',') for  x in df["LIST OF POSITIVE DATES"]]

df["LIST OF POSITIVE DATES"] = df["LIST OF POSITIVE DATES"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d",errors="coerce").date)`
```

This creates a DateTime object for each list item.

Then I calculate the difference as

```
df["DIFFERENCE"]= (df["DATE OF ADMISSION"] - df["LIST OF POSITIVE DATES"])
```

This code does the work of calculating the difference between the DATE OF ADMISSION and each of the items in the LIST OF POSITIVE DATES. However, it produces a nested result of date-times, that I am not able to use to retrieve INT and that also contains hours.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrnH3.png).

Here is a snapshot of the data

| LIST OF POSITIVE DATES | PATIENT ID | DATE OF ADMISSION | DATE OF DISCHARGE | IN-HOSPITAL POSITIVITY | BEFORE HOSPITALIZATION | POST-HOSPITALIZATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [2020-11-11] | 1 | 2019-07-01 | 2019-07-05 | If a date in "LIST OF POS DATES" is within DATE OF ADMISSION and DATE OF DISCHARGE | If the POSITIVE TEST happened within 15 days before DATE OF ADMISSION | If positive test happened 15 days after DATE OF DISCHARGE |
| [2020-10-16] | 2 | 2019-07-02 | 2019-07-05 |  |  |  |
| [2020-11-09] | 3 | 2018-11-09 | 2019-01-23 |  |  |  |
| [2021-03-23,2021-04-06,2021-04-15] | 4 | 2018-12-10 | 2019-01-29 |  |  |  |
| [2020-11-11,2020-11-14] | 5 | 2018-12-20 | 2019-01-04 |  |  |  |
| [2020-11-17] | 5 | 2018-12-23 | 2019-01-02 |  |  |  |
| [2021-03-18,2021-03-23] | 1 | 2018-12-24 | 2019-01-07 |  |  |  |
| [2020-11-27,2020-12-21] | 2 | 2018-12-25 | 2019-01-09 |  |  |  |
| [2020-12-02] | 3 | 2018-12-25 | 2019-01-12 |  |  |  |
| [2020-11-10,2020-11-19] | 4 | 2018-12-28 | 2019-01-09 |  |  |  |
| [2020-11-28,2020-12-09,2020-12-16,2020-12-23] | 5 | 2018-12-29 | 2019-01-05 |  |  |  |
| [2020-11-10,2020-11-25] | 5 | 2018-12-30 | 2019-01-04 |  |  |  |
| [2020-11-04] | 1 | 2018-12-30 | 2019-01-02 |  |  |  |
| [2021-10-28,2021-11-08] | 2 | 2018-12-30 | 2019-01-02 |  |  |  |
| [2021-01-01] | 3 | 2018-12-30 | 2019-01-03 |  |  |  |
| [2021-03-10] | 4 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-22 |  |  |  |
| [2020-10-24,2020-11-03] | 5 | 2019-01-02 | 2019-12-31 |  |  |  |
| [2020-10-10,2020-10-22,2021-04-13] | 5 | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-07 |  |  |  |

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgmiZ.png

NEW SCRENSHOT OF NEW OUTPUT HERE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRu1N.jpg)

Comment: Could you post some example data along with the expected output? That would be helpful.

Comment: Explode List of POS Date, then subtract column by column and you aggregrate back to list if needed.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632)

Comment: @CarmenMorales, the column names don't match between your code and the given example. By the way, this one isn't meaningful since it will give the same result for all the rows. Can you at least, show how should look like the three new columns `IN-HOSPITAL POSITIVITY` , `BEFORE HOSPITALIZATION` and `POST-HOSPITALIZATION` ? Are they supposed to be booleans `"Yes/No"` ?

Comment: @Timeless, yes they can be boolean. Thank you. I fixed my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
compare_cols = [
    "LIST OF POSITIVE DATES",
    "DATE OF ADMISSION",
    "DATE OF DISCHARGE"
]

list_of_checks = [
    1 if any(adm <= pd.Timestamp(dt) <= dis for dt in lst)
    else 2 if any(0 <= (adm - pd.Timestamp(dt)).days <= 15 for dt in lst)
    else 3 if any(0 <= (pd.Timestamp(dt) - dis).days <= 15 for dt in lst)
    else "NA" for (lst, adm, dis) in df[compare_cols].to_numpy()
]

df["Positivity"] = list_of_checks
```

**Old answer :**

Since the expected output is not fully clear, here is a proposition :

```
# uncomment (if needed)
# df["LIST OF POSITIVE DATES"] = (
#     df["LIST OF POSITIVE DATES"].str.strip("[]").str.split(",\s*")
# ); date_cols = ["DATE OF ADMISSION", "DATE OF DISCHARGE"]
# df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

---

```
compare_cols = [
    "LIST OF POSITIVE DATES",
    "DATE OF ADMISSION",
    "DATE OF DISCHARGE"
]

results_cols = [
    "IN-HOSPITAL POSITIVITY",
    "BEFORE HOSPITALIZATION",
    "POST-HOSPITALIZATION"
]

list_of_checks = [
    (
        any(adm <= pd.Timestamp(dt) <= dis for dt in lst),
        any(0 <= (adm - pd.Timestamp(dt)).days <= 15 for dt in lst),
        any(0 <= (pd.Timestamp(dt) - dis).days <= 15 for dt in lst),     
    ) for (lst, adm, dis) in df[compare_cols].to_numpy()

]

checks = pd.DataFrame(list_of_checks, dtype="int", columns=results_cols)

out = df.join(checks)
```

Output :

```
print(checks)

    IN-HOSPITAL POSITIVITY  BEFORE HOSPITALIZATION  POST-HOSPITALIZATION
0                        0                       0                     1
1                        0                       0                     1
2                        0                       0                     1
3                        0                       0                     1
4                        0                       0                     1
..                     ...                     ...                   ...
13                       0                       0                     1
14                       0                       0                     1
15                       0                       0                     1
16                       0                       0                     1
17                       0                       0                     1

[18 rows x 3 columns]
```

Used input :

```
print(df.sample())

     LIST OF POSITIVE DATES  PATIENT ID DATE OF ADMISSION DATE OF DISCHARGE
11  [2020-11-10,2020-11-25]           5        2018-12-30        2019-01-04
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach! You are a saviour.

What does .str.strip("[]").str.split(",\s*")  does to the list? 

I think the logic of checks is not working. I probably have said them in the wrong way.   The in-hospital one is correct and gives the right results. The others are not. I will share this picture to make it more understandable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgmiZ.png
How can I change the logic to account for this?

Basically, it is about discovering whether the patient got positive 15 days before the DATE of Admission, or within 15 days after the discharge.

Comment: You're welcome! `.str.strip("[]").str.split(",\s*")` is making a list of date-like strings `["dt1", "dt2", ..]` from the original string `"[dt1,dt2,..]"` (*see how the double quotes are placed before/after the strip/split*). Regarding your second point, I checked your screenshot but It doesn't show why the 2/3 computations are wrong. Can you give an example of a single row with wrong values ? Can you `print(df.iloc[5])` with `5` being its index ?

Comment: Thank you. Here result of printing index 5.

| Field                   | Value                   |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|
| List of POS Dates       | [2020-11-17]            |
| DATE ADMISSION          | 2018-12-23 00:00:00     |
| DATE DISCHARGE          | 2019-01-02 00:00:00     |
| IN-HOSPITAL POSITIVITY  | 0                       |
| BEFORE HOSPITALIZATION  | 0                       |
| POST-HOSPITALIZATION    | 1                       |

The Column POST-HOSP should be one if the date in the list is within 15 days after  the date of discharge

Comment: I have modified the last checks as any( 0 <= (pd.Timestamp(dt) - dis).days <= 15 for dt in last). Now it works. Thank you so much for the wonderful code.

Comment: You're welcome and good catch ;) I updated the answer with your fix.

Comment: Hello @Timeless. I am writing again to ask if you could modify the code you posted to suit a new function.  Rather than returning one column with dummy values, it would be nice to have only one column with different values. For example, taking Value 1 when the positive is in between admission and discharge. Could you give me some suggestions on how to approach it? thank you

Comment: @CarmenMorales, what should be the column name and how the values should be computed ? Also , can you make a screenshot of with a small example of your input/expected-output ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Column name "Positivity". Value "1" when adm <= pd.Timestamp(dt) <= dis is met ; Value "2" when condition 0 <= (adm - pd.Timestamp(dt)).days <= 15 is met; Value "3" when any(0 <= (pd.Timestamp(dt) - dis).days <= 15 is met; I added the screenshot on the main post

Comment: Thanks for amending. I added an update at the top of my answer. You may be need to adjust the order of the values (`1`, `2`, `3`, ..) but most importantly, you have the *general logic*. Happy coding ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am learning a lot. I have a question. Can you please explain How it is possible that when you declare the compare_columns list it is an empty dataframe but then it is populated? Does the population happen at the pd.Dataframe operation?

Comment: You're welcome ;) If you refer to the old approach where we call the [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor, the answer is yes. This one accepts many types of inputs and a nested list is one of them. When we pass an input like `nl = [["v11", "v12", "v13"], ["v21", "v22", "v23"]]` (*2 nested lists with 3 elements each*), the construction `pd.DataFrame(nl)` will make a DataFrame of 2 rows and 3 columns. `v11` will be populated at the *1st-row/1st-col*, `v22`, at *2nd-row/2nd-col* and so on.. `list_of_checks` is an example of `nl`.

Comment: Ok understood. Thank you. One last (I swear :S) question. A problem arose because some "List of Positive Dates" are empty. Hence I got the error "float object is not iterable". I know that it is missing value because when I drop  them it works. I tried to substitute np.nan with pd.NaT but it does not work as I got the same non-iterability error.

Comment: No worries ;) A simple workaround would be to use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) like this : `... for (lst, adm, dis) in df[compare_cols].fillna({"LIST OF POSITIVE DATES": ""}).to_numpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can approach this problem

**1. Create the dataframe**

```py
admission_dates = ["01/01/2020", "02/02/2020", "03/01/2020"]
discharge_dates = ["05/01/2020", "10/02/2020", "15/01/2020"]
pos_dates = [["01/01/2020", "02/02/2020", "03/01/2020"], ["05/01/2020", "10/02/2020", "15/01/2020"], ["05/01/2020", "10/02/2020", "31/01/2020"]]
df = pd.DataFrame({"admission":admission_dates, "discharge":discharge_dates, "pos":pos_dates})
```

This gives

[image: Image of dataframe]

**2. Next we need to explode the positive dates. That means expand it so that there is one date per row**

```py
df = df.explode("pos")
```

This gives

[image: Image of data after exploding the pos column]

**3. Now we convert to datetimes**

```py
df["admission"] = pd.to_datetime(df["admission"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df["discharge"] = pd.to_datetime(df["discharge"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df["pos"] = pd.to_datetime(df["pos"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

and we have

[image: Data with converted dates]

**4. Finally we can do some calculations. For example: To calculate the rows where a positive date is between admission and discharge**

```py
df[(df.pos < df.discharge) & (df.admission < df.pos)]
```

gives us

[image: Final result]

Comment: Thank you. 
Is there a way to "implode" them back again? This is because I need the data format to have one row for each observation.

Comment: @CarmenMorales To implode you can use groupby + agg. For example 
`df.groupby(df.index).agg({"admission":"first", "discharge":"first", "pos":lambda x: x.tolist()})`